# Bootstrap carrousel no encuentra mi imagen

Tags: html, bootstrap, img

Hola amigos no sé porque mi carrousel de bootstrap no encuenta mis imagenes, en las herramientas de developer puedo ver que estoy referenciando bien las imagenes proque si llegan, pero no me las muestra, alguien podría decirme si estoy haciendo algo mal??

```
<div class="col-sm-3 centro carrusel-margen">

                        <!-- <img class="img-fluid" src="images/no-img.jpg"> -->

                    <div id="carrusel-mailings" class="carousel slide tam-carrusel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
        <!--                    

                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
                            <li data-target="#carrusel-mailings" data-slide-to="5" class=""></li> -->
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-2-noviembre.jpg?v=21">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-3-noviembre.jpg?v=22">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-4-noviembre.jpg?v=23">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-1.jpg?v=24">
                            </div>



    <!--                        
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-1.jpg?v=22">
                            </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-3.jpg?v=23">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-5.jpg?v=22">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-6.jpg?v=22">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-7.jpg?v=22">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-8.jpg?v=22">
                            </div> -->
                        </div>

                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carrusel-mailings" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carrusel-mailings" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div> 

                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo único raro que noto es que después de la extensión, sigue un **?v=** ... el nombre de la imagen física es la misma????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ya está , siempre el primer elemento debe tener la clase active al lado de carousel-item, si no bootstrap no puede iniciar el carrusel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div class="carousel-item active"> <!--Aquì me faltaba el active-->
 <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/view-mailing-2-noviembre.jpg?v=21">
 </div>
```

Comment: Porfavor escribí el código en lugar de pegar una captura